# #define to double - different value?

Tags: c++, c, double, c-preprocessor

Here are two different ways I'm defining the same value. I want it to exist as a 64-bit (double precision) float point number (aka double).

```
#define THISVALUE -0.148759f

double myDouble = -0.148759;
```

If I perform the following operation

```
double tryingIt = THISVALUE;
```

and I look at the value during debugging or print it, I can see it assigns `tryingIt` to **-0.14875899255275726**

I understand that a floating point is not exact but this is just a crazy difference that really throws off my math. Directly assigning the double as in top code block gives me a value of **-0.14875900000000000** in the debugger - exactly what it should be.

Any thoughts on what's up?

Comment: Most probably the single precision literal `f` is causing the difference you are seeing. `-0.148759` is double precision and `-0.148759f` is single precision.

Comment: Is this C or C++? C/C++ is non-existent. If this is C, `#define` is (de)fine. If not, there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because `-0.148759f` is not a `double`, it's a `float`. Hence it's almost certainly the differing precision which is making a difference.

Either of these two variations should give you identical results:

```
#define THISVALUE -0.148759
double myDouble = -0.148759;  // Both double.

#define THISVALUE -0.148759f
double myDouble = -0.148759f; // Both float.
```

IEEE754 single precision values (commonly used in `float`) have only 32 bits available to them so have limited range and precision compared to double precision values (which have 64 bits).

As per [the Wikipedia page on IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), *rough* figures for range and precision are:

- For `singles`, range `±10±38` with 7 digits precision.
- For `doubles`, range `±10±308` with 15 digits precision.

---

And, as an aside, there's nowhere near as much reason for using macros nowadays, either for functions *or* objects. The former can be done with the `inline` suggestion and good compilers, the latter can be done with `const int` (or `const double` in your case) without losing any information between compilation stages (things like names and type information).

Comment: Ahh, my mistake! I thought the f was required to specify either float or double, not just float. Question - I'm doing this to save memory for a VERY memory-tight environment... I figured setting all of my constants (there are over 100 of them) with the #define directive would save me RAM since it only loads the values into memory when they're required instead of keeping them hanging around in the global scope all the time. Suggestions?

Comment: @Pugz, it _may_ save memory but, unless you're running on an embedded system with 1K available, 100 x 8 bytes isn't going to make much of a difference :-)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm running on. Meh, it's got almost 2K. :-) Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot C uses double as the default floating point and float was an after-thought. Oops.

Comment: @Pugz, then by all means use `#define`. You may find that something like `const static int` would give you the same effect but you'd have to test. If you have that sort of constraint, you _may_ also want to use floats instead of doubles, since they'll take up half the space. That's assuming the loss of range/precision is acceptable.

Comment: Loss of precision is not acceptable. Most values are something like 1.405615421515

Comment: The _other_ possibility, since it may be the case that a system with only 2K is underpowered in other areas like CPU grunt, is to use integral types. You can use fixed-point stuff if you still need fractional values. But this should really be in another question, so as to get the full force of SO giving you options.

Comment: Ick. I think I'll stay away from that and see how these #define's do for now.

Answer (score 19):

You have a trailing `f` in the `define`:

```
#define THISVALUE -0.148759f
                           ^
                           |
```

Which means that the literal in question is `float` precision, instead of the `double` default that you need. Remove that character.